# What's the actionscript to detect the domain at which a flex app is currently running?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

How do I programatically detect from Flex/Actionscript the STRING representing the current security domain, as used by LocalConnection.AllowDomain?

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unclear if this answers your question, but to get the domain that hte SWF is being served from use [Application.url](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/Application.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#url) to get the URL Serving the SWF and then use [URLUtils.getServerName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/utils/URLUtil.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#getServerName%28%29) to get the actual domain.

The LocalConnection class also has a [domain](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/LocalConnection.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#domain) property, which looks like a shortcut for the above if you're using a LocalConnection.

I believe either of those will give you the current domain.  It sounds like you want to know the name of the domain trying to access your SWF, though.  If so, I do not know of a way to get that information.,